# Two gridview from two model search by single field in yii2

Tags: yii2

I have one search form with a field and a button. On the button click I want to search 2 searchmodel - `sellitembtdtSearch` and `puritembtdtSearch`. The result will be shown in one view. I can display the view without any problem. The problem is when I'm searching only one searchmodel is getting searched. Please let me know how can I search both the searchModel at the sametime.

First I land on index2.php page where the form is.

```
'action' => ['/stock/sellitem/printproductledger3',],
'method' => 'get',
<?= $form->field($model, 'productname')->textInput(['maxlength' => true,]) ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

actionIndex2.php

```
public function actionIndex2()
    {
        $searchModel1 = new SellitemsbdtSearch();
        $dataProvider1 = $searchModel1->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $searchModel2 = new PuritemsbdtSearch();
        $dataProvider2 = $searchModel2->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('_formbtdt', [ 

            'model' => $searchModel2,
            //'searchModel1' => $searchModel2,
        ]);
    }

public function actionPrintproductledger3() {

        $searchModel1  = new SellitemsbdtSearch();
        $dataProvider1 = $searchModel1->search(Yii::$app->request->get());
        $searchModel2  = new PuritemsbdtSearch();
        $dataProvider2 = $searchModel2->search(Yii::$app->request->get());
        //$productname = yii::$app->request->get('productname');
        //$prodesc = yii::$app->request->get('prodesc');

        $content = $this->renderPartial('_printproductledgerbtdt', [
            //'productname' => $productname,            
            'searchModel1' => $searchModel1,          
            'dataProvider1' => $dataProvider1,
            'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,          
            'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,            
            //'prodesc' => $prodesc,

            ]);
return $this->render('_printproductledgerbtdt', [
            'dataProvider1' => $dataProvider1,
            'searchModel1'  => $searchModel1,
            'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,          
            'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,
        ]);
```

[image]

This code only searchs `puritemdtdtSearch`. I want to search `puritembtdtSearch` and `sellitembtdtSearch` at the same time. Thanks.

Comment: have you considered using ajax? and what do you mean by you need to search to different searchModels... you can just search 1 searchModel and use relations if they are related

Comment: Yes. here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41900399/display-pdf-in-browser-by-calling-controller-action-by-ajax-in-yii2...

Comment: They have a common field but as I want to display two separate gridview, I want to build  separate search models.

Comment: no. they are not related.

Comment: So you have two grid views you mean?

Comment: One will come from sellitembtdtSearch and other will from puritemsearchbtdtSearch. And both will be displayed on a singe view. I'm adding a desired output in the question.

Comment: I've added a desired output. You can see, the left gridview is filtered by pi_upc but the right gridview is not filtered by si_iupc. That is the problem.

Comment: So in one view you are using multiple models?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135375/discussion-between-mohan-prasad-and-tanmay).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are using searchModel2 in your form so you are just getting the result of searchModel2. And not getting the result of searchModel1.

- What you can do is send searchModel1 to your _search file.

  ```
   <?php echo $this->render('_search', ['model1' => $searchModel1, 'model2' => $searchModel2]); ?>
  ```
- Now in your form use a hidden input.

  ```
      <?php echo $form->field($model1, 'productName')->textInput(['id' => 'model1']); ?>
      <?php echo $form->field($model2, 'prodcutName')->hiddenInput(array('id' => 'model2')); ?>
  ```
- Now its that we have two model fields we need to populate the hidden field, this can be done using jquery.

  ```
      <?php $this->registerJs('
           //add the .search class name for your search button
          jQuery("body").on("click", ".search", function() {
          alert("Hello");
          var a = $("#model1").val(); 
          $("#model2").attr("value", a);
        });
     ');?>
  ```

Try this..tested completely and works fine!!